# Using GoogleFit API in a non-activity/fragment class

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm making an app that requires steps to be counted in the background. In a JobService class I'd like to connect to the GoogleFit API and read the steps. The issue I'm having is I can't get GoogleFit to connect. My log "Working" shows, but none of the logs for the Fit connections appear, which leads me to believe the connection is never happening. I tried starting the client builder in onCreate() and onStartJob(), neither worked. Any ideas?

```
public class BackgroundStepTracker extends JobService implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks{
public static final String JOB_TAG = BackgroundStepTracker.class.getName();

private GoogleApiClient mClient = null;
public static final String TAG = "BACKGROUND";
private Context _context;
private SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;


private static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES = "SHAREDPREFERENCES";


public BackgroundStepTracker(){
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    _sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);

    _context = getApplicationContext();

}

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Working");

    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(_context)
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .build();

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Stopping");

    return false;
}

public void subscribe() {
    // To create a subscription, invoke the Recording API. As soon as the subscription is
    // active, fitness data will start recording.
    Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(mClient, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        if (status.getStatusCode()
                                == FitnessStatusCodes.SUCCESS_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Existing subscription for activity detected.");
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.");
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
    // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.  What to do?
    // Subscribe to some data sources!
    subscribe();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
    // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
    if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
    } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
}
```

Comment: the onConnectionFailed method is empty. maybe adding a logging statement to the body of that method would reveal a useful clue.

Comment: I added a log in onConnectionFailed() and it never shows. Not sure if the connection is even attempted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake was not calling mClient.connect() after building it. This solved my issue.